# Rails 3 i18n, can't seem to customize model attribute name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

In Rails 3, I'm trying to customize the name of some model attributes when they appear in form errors.  My `User` model has a field named `initial_zip`, and I would like to present errors on this field in the name `Zip code` instead.

[It looks like I'm supposed to do this via locales.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models)  So I added the following to my `en.yml`

**config/locales/en.yml**

```
en:
  active_record:
    attributes:
      user:
        initial_zip: Zip code
```

However, when I register a new user without an `initial_zip` I get the validation error message:

```
"Initial zip can't be blank"
```

I expected to get this instead:

```
"Zip code can't be blank"
```

I did find this in snippet in `application.rb`, but the comment seems to say that the default is just what I want (:en default locale and loading form config/locales).  So I left it commented.

**config/application.rb**

```
# The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
# config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
# config.i18n.default_locale = :de
```

Any idea what I did wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you need quotes around your `Zip code` string.

```
en:
  active_record:
    attributes:
      user:
        initial_zip: "Zip code"
```